# UITextField não pega o valor de texto de uma Array Swift

Tags: array, swift, uitextfield

Galera estou usando core data para salvar o input do usuário em uma array. Até ai o código funciona perfeitamente, o problema é na hora de pegar algum elemento dessa array e colocar no UITextField. O código não apresenta erros, só não funciona como deveria.

```
@IBOutlet weak var quoteTextField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var addQuote: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var deleteQuote: UIButton!

var bookArray: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    //Pega todas as quotes guardadas no CoreData
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "BookArray")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    bookArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

    if (bookArray.count != 0){
        var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(bookArray.count)))
        quoteTextField.text = bookArray[randomIndex] as? String

    }
}
```

Comment: Skal, se você colocar um print(bookArray[randomIndex]) ele te retorna o que?
veja se tem diferença entre os retornos de String e Int
*tive que escrever aqui pois não consigo fazer comentarios*

Comment: A sua entidade se chama BookArray? Se sim, ela é um objeto complexo, e deve ter um atributo String, por isso o erro. Tentar o cast (as?) de um objeto complexo para uma string irá retornar nulo. Tente bookArray[randomIndex].nomeDeSeuAtributo as? String